How do I add a class to HTML tags in CKEditor 5?
In Drupal 7, I could add classes for <img> and <div> tags in CKEditor 4. I can’t find a comparable feature in CKEditor 5.
How can I add classes to these tags using CKEditor 5?

Thanks Clive for correcting my question. In Ckeditor 4 there is another feature wrapper '' tag But it seems this feature is not available in Ckeditor 5.
